# Node js. Where is memory leak?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, snapshot, retained-in-memory

I'm trying to find memory leak in my snapshots.
[Snaphot 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByoUBbB_2XqaT3N1cTk0UHN6WGM)
[Snaphot 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByoUBbB_2XqaSW9WMllxVFBlT28)

I see that an array is growing, but I can't find any leaks inside.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please try to narrow the code. Why would anyone want to look through long files to find a simple mistake? As you make the code smaller, you will find the leak.

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from 3 snapshot method. Check out http://www.alexkras.com/simple-guide-to-finding-a-javascript-memory-leak-in-node-js/ for more info and example.